# Why does this Tower of Hanoi program work?

Tags: java, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I'm a complete beginner at coding, and I was working on a few simple mini-projects to get more familiar with java. When I encountered this Tower of Hanoi code.

```
public class TowersOfHanoi {

    public void solve(int n, String start, String auxiliary, String end) {
        if (n == 1) {
            System.out.println(start + " -> " + end);
        } else {
            solve(n - 1, start, end, auxiliary);
            System.out.println(start + " -> " + end);
            solve(n - 1, auxiliary, start, end);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TowersOfHanoi towersOfHanoi = new TowersOfHanoi();
        System.out.print("Enter number of discs: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int discs = scanner.nextInt();
        towersOfHanoi.solve(discs, "A", "B", "C");
       }
    }
```

I understand how the puzzle works; however, I can't understand how this code knows where to move the respective pieces of the tower without violating the rule that a larger piece cannot rest atop a smaller one.
Additionally, because of my very weak understanding of code, I thought that `if (n==1){` was not true then it moves on to the else. But instead of that even when I enter values for `n` that aren't `1` the code moves to utilize the information directly under the `if` statement instead of jumping to the `else` line beneath it.

For example if my `scanner` input was 4, then the way I previously understood it, the code would set the `scanner`'s input to the `int discs` and funnel that to the `towersOfHanoi.solve(discs,"A", "B", "C");`. So wouldn't that mean when the program pulls up the `.solve` method `int n` would be equal to `4`? And again wouldn't the code check to see if `if(n==1){` which it shouldn't...as I thought it would be `(4==1)`.

I do know that this is a recursive solution to the problem, but does that really affect the rules of how java processes the code?

P.S. I apologize if I used any terminology wrong or if I'm not clear enough, I'm teaching myself and so I don't have anyone else to ask my questions... Also I didn't make this code, I found it on a site that had a recursive version of the java source code solution to the puzzle.

Comment: Play the game along with the program. When n = 4, the *recursive* case is called; n is decremented every time the method is recursively called. Each invocation of a method has it's *own distinct parameter* (n = 4, then n = 3 in a *different* invocation, then..), even though the names are 'shared' across calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that if (n==1){ was not true then it moves on to the else.
>   But instead of that even when I enter values for n that aren't 1 the
>   code moves to utilize the information directly under the if statement

What you thought holds on for your input unless the value of the chained input ***reduces to 1***, because of the following statement, e.g.:-

```
solve(n - 1, start, end, auxiliary);
```

---

Let's say when you provide n =3,

At 1st iteration, control moves to `else` and calls the same method with

```
solve(2, start, end, auxiliary)
```

At 2nd iteration, it reaches `else` and calls again with

```
solve(1, start, end, auxiliary) // and you know this would reach if(n==1) next time
```

---

The above iterations are the effect of recursion, wherein you're calling the same method from within with different values. The statement

```
if(n==1)
```

is precisely the tail of your recursion and is a must to exit out of it, hence would always be reached.

Comment: thank you so much, that helped clear so much confusion up!

Comment: @GilgameshCraos cool, if it was helpful, do accept it as an answer :)